# Trying to show zero instyead of #Error in visual studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio I want to state that if a calculation box is blank due to there being no figures available on that particluar project, then show zero.

My calculation is a very simple:

```
=(ReportItems!textbox21.Value) /
 (ReportItems!textbox19.Value)
```

For this I wrote an IIf statement:

```
=IIf(
   IsNothing(ReportItems!textbox21.Value) Or 
     IsNothing(ReportItems!textbox19.Value), 
   0,
   ((ReportItems!textbox21.Value)/(ReportItems!textbox19.Value)))
```

But this still shows as #Error if there is a blank in either of textbox 21 or 19.  see below picture.

[image]

Can anyone advise on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it by inserting the below function:-

```
Function Divide(Numerator as Double, Denominator as Double)
If Denominator = 0 Then
Return 0
Else
Return Numerator/Denominator
End If
End Function
```

and then re-writing my calculation as :-

```
=Code.Divide(ReportItems!textbox21.Value, ReportItems!textbox19.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use IsNumeric instead of Isnothing,

`=IIf(IsNumeric(ReportItems!textbox21.Value) and IsNumeric(ReportItems!textbox19.Value),((ReportItems!textbox21.Value)/(ReportItems!textbox19.Value)), 0)`

Comment: there is no error message that appears just the calculation result.  I have updated my original post to show the calculation that appears

Comment: thanks for all suggestions.  I managed to fix it with the below coding

Answer (score 0):

Can you try instead of IsNothing convert the value as string and compare with string.empty

`IsNothing(ReportItems!textbox21.Value)`

changed as,

`ReportItems!textbox21.Value.ToString() = ""`